# What does http and https module do in Node?

Tags: node.js, express

Can someone help me in understanding what does http and https module do in Express?

I was going through the following [docs on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp)

From definition it says

> Node.js has a built-in module called HTTP, which allows Node.js to
>   transfer data over the Hyper Text Transfer Protocol (HTTP).

With following example

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

This is the example to [live demo](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs.asp?filename=demo_http)

**First,** I am unable to comprehend their example like **Where** are they making (route) request so that they are receiving response?

**Second** by the definition, to make a request, using libraries like axios can be alternative?

**third,** when we make an api request, isn't the data transferred over http/https?

```
app.post("/", (req, res) =>  {
```

In short, Can someone please explain me in more human words the use of http package in express?

**Update:** I might be confusing this with express, I am used to using express and here we aren't using express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- They aren't defining any route. That piece of code only creates a server running on port 8080 that when it's created or accessed on the home route (/) returns "Hello World". If you want to define routes you should take a closer look to a module called *express* that it's used by most of node users due to its simplicity and documentation (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) In that link you have an example for creating the server and a basic route

2- Yes it can and should be because they are way better than the default from nodeJs. Take a look at axios or superagent, superagent it's better if you want to use formdata to send images or attachments.

3- By default, all servers created using http or express are http servers (don't have a certificate to encrypt the data so they aren't secure). If you want a https server, you can buy certificates or use https://letsencrypt.org/ this module that generates free SSL certificates with 1 month validation.

http module has multiple functions, it can be used to create a server, to make http requests and so on. It's up to you to decide which submodule from the package you want to use. Express is built over the *http* module making everything easier.

If you need more explanation, tell me and I will try to explain a little better.